# BlueJ - GUI JTextField, how to make the corners of it round like an oval?

Tags: user-interface, jtextfield, rounded-corners, bluej

How do I make the corners of a TextField round?
I'm using Javax.swing.*;

Here's my code for BlueJ:

```
inputLine = new JTextField();
inputLine.setBounds(480, 350, 150, 30);
contentPane.add(inputLine);  
inputLine.setForeground(Color.black);
inputLine.setBackground(Color.white);
inputLine.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
inputLine.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
inputLine.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
inputLine.setEditable(true);
contentPane.add(inputLine);
inputLine.addActionListener(this);
inputLine.setText("ID Number");
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do, is first create a Jframe window.
If you want only a text Field, make the dimensions of the j Frame a bit bigger than the preferred text Field size.
Then, set the layout of the jFrame to absolute.
Create a Jlabel that covers the whole screen Jframe.
Create the text Field only after this step.
Then create the text Field at the preferred location in the j Frame.
Design a graphic / picture for the background and set the icon of the background jLabel to the graphic you have designed.
The graphic you have designed must have a rounded rectangular picture in it and the text Field must be exactly positioned on top of that.
Once that is done set the opacity of the Text Field to 0.0. This should work very well...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
jframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));

[please add the other methods to create a jframe window...these are only the basic commands]

pane.setLayout(null);//makes it an absolute layout so that it does not reshape itself
```

frame.setVisible(true);
after doing this, design your graphics.
then:
import it into the current working directory, where this program has been written.
then:
create a jLabel inside the jFrame.

```
 JLabel label1 = new JLabel("JLabel Set Icon Example.");
```

set its icon to the graphic you have designed.

```
label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("full path of the image _ with the proper file extension"));
```

then

```
textField = new JTextField(desired value);//please add the desired value into the brackets

//set its location and all the other thing that are required
```

set the location of the textField exactly over the the rounded rectangle in the graphic.

then:

```
textField.isOpaque("false");

jTextField1.setBorder(null);//this should work
```

and there you go...the user will think that the textField is a rounded rectangle but actually it is like a rectangle which has a transparent background...

let me know if there are any problems.
thanks.